# how to convert the fetched data of getJson in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

my question is simple, how to convert this:

```
$.getJSON("https://estudiomiramonte.com/app/api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=" + "146");
```

on this:

```
var data1 = {"data":[{"impuesto":"IVA","idConcepto":"30","id":"266","datos":{"anticipo":"PRESENTACION","vencimiento":"2017-09-18","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"IVA","idConcepto":"30","id":"267","datos":{"anticipo":"PAGO","vencimiento":"2017-09-18","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"GANANCIAS SOCIEDADES","idConcepto":"10","id":"268","datos":{"anticipo":"PAGO","vencimiento":"2017-09-13","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"SICORE-IMPTO.A LAS GANANCIAS","idConcepto":"217","id":"269","datos":{"anticipo":"PAGO","vencimiento":"2017-09-11","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"EMPLEADOR-APORTES SEG. SOCIAL","idConcepto":"301","id":"270","datos":{"anticipo":"PRESENTACION","vencimiento":"2017-09-07","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"EMPLEADOR-APORTES SEG. SOCIAL","idConcepto":"301","id":"271","datos":{"anticipo":"PAGO","vencimiento":"2017-09-07","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"PRESENTAC. DJ RET. Y\/O PERCEP","idConcepto":"220","id":"272","datos":{"anticipo":"PRESENTACION","vencimiento":"2017-09-11","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"GANANCIAS SOCIEDADES","idConcepto":"10","id":"273","datos":{"anticipo":"PRESENTACION","vencimiento":"2017-11-13","agencia":"AFIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales","idConcepto":"2","id":"274","datos":{"anticipo":"anticipo 01","vencimiento":"19\/01\/2018","agencia":"ARBA","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral","idConcepto":"2","id":"275","datos":{"anticipo":"anticipo 01","vencimiento":"15\/01\/2018","agencia":"ARBA","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"IB","idConcepto":"1","id":"276","datos":{"anticipo":"recaudacion","vencimiento":"2017-01-07","agencia":"AGIP","id_perfil":"146"}},{"impuesto":"IB","idConcepto":"3","id":"277","datos":{"anticipo":"Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral","vencimiento":"2017-01-13","agencia":"AGIP","id_perfil":"146"}}]}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). it has numerous examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?

Comment: I want to have only the object as a variable, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s42owhdf/1/

Comment: @shios, you can do that as JSingh (or the other examples in the documentation) suggests. Simply process the data within a callback function. Although note, `get2 =` in your fiddle is not valid Json.

Comment: can you give me an example @p.s.w.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data;
$.getJSON("https://estudiomiramonte.com/app/api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=" + "146")
.done(function(res){
  data = res;
  // only first element data array.
  console.log(data['data'][0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you need ??

Comment: I need to delete or filter repeated data from get2 on get1

Comment: i've edited your example, let me know if it helps you

Comment: I can not find what you edited but the fiddle does not work. however your answer to my question is correct, thanks.

Comment: I can post the answer here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155631/discussion-between-jsingh-and-shios).